# Microsoft Graph Subscriptions - Call Records

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

So I have a use case that I need to receive call records from Microsoft Teams calls.  I found documentation on a Microsoft Graph call that allows for this, located: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Inside this page, it also mentions that Call Records can be sent to a web hook using Graph Subscriptions.  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

It says I need to grant Application API Permission to https://graph.microsoft.com/CallRecords.Read.All.  I created a new app registration with only this permission on it.

I did Administrative Consent for the Organization.

I requested a Bearer token from [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D/v2.0) with scope of https://graph.microsoft.com/.default.

I post to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions with a body of:

```
{
  "changeType": "created",
  "notificationUrl": "xxx",
  "resource": "/communications/callRecords",
  "expirationDateTime": "2021-03-03T11:00:00.0000000Z"
}
```

On my endpoint receiving notifications, I am replying with the validation Token, and I see that request / response coming in from the Graph API to my endpoint, and it successfully returns a 200 with the token.

My Post response comes back with a 403 Forbidden.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: The request is not authorized for this user or application.]",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-03-02T15:32:36",
      "request-id": "21ac082f-e2a4-41e0-badf-4672e5b05cc8",
      "client-request-id": "21ac082f-e2a4-41e0-badf-4672e5b05cc8"
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas on what step I'm missing?

Comment: Which API call that you're trying to do? Check the token using https://jwt.ms has necessary permissions to see if it has necessary scopes/permissions to access the given workload/resource.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are pointing to the correct App Registration